# Insect identification - Possible grasshopper or grass beetle

Tags: species-identification, entomology

We found a small insect on our window and we cannot decide whether it is a type of grasshopper or grass beetle. It doesn't seem to want to fly, but was on a first floor bedroom window, and walks slowly and has a strong grip on the window and petri dish. We live on the outskirts of a town in Essex, UK and it could have come from a field, but they are on the other side of the house. It is a small brown insect (the main body is approximately 2cm long) with 6 legs, and the back 2 legs seem to bigger than the others.
[image: Beetle front]
[image: Beetle back]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Neither beetle nor grasshopper, it is a hemipteran, Coreidae. *Leptoglossus occidentalis* or 
Western Conifer Seed Bug.  https://www.britishbugs.org.uk/heteroptera/Coreidae/leptoglossus_occidentalis.html

Comment: This idenification looks good. Insects of this genus seem to have  variable spine arragements on their femurs. I'd like to know more about that.